# appxmanifest.xml for adaptive scaling assets

Tags: uwp, assets, desktop-bridge

I am building a windows brdige app, and trying to include adaptive scaling assets for the tiles and such. However, when building the package, makeappx complains about non-existing files.

I use the following appxmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress XmlUnusedNamespaceDeclaration -->
<Package
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
   xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
   xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
   xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities">
  <!-- use single quotes to avoid double quotes escaping in the publisher value  -->
  <Identity Name="IRMASignatureApp"
    ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
    Publisher='CN=ms'
    Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>IRMASignatureApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Privacy By Design Foundatation</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Description>An IRMA app to create IRMA signatures</Description>
    <Logo>assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-US" />
  </Resources>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14316.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14316.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="IRMASignatureApp" Executable="app\IRMASignatureApp.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <uap:VisualElements
       BackgroundColor="#464646"
       DisplayName="IRMASignatureApp"
       Square150x150Logo="assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
       Square44x44Logo="assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
       Description="An IRMA app to create IRMA signatures">

        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />

      </uap:VisualElements>

    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

However, on running makeappx, i get the following errors:

```
MakeAppx : error: Manifest validation error: Line 33, Column 8, Reason: The file name "assets\Square150x150Logo.png" declared for element "*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']/*[local-name()='VisualElements']" doesn't exist in the package.
MakeAppx : error: Manifest validation error: Line 34, Column 8, Reason: The file name "assets\Square44x44Logo.png" declared for element "*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']/*[local-name()='VisualElements']" doesn't exist in the package.
MakeAppx : error: Manifest validation error: Line 37, Column 26, Reason: The file name "assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" declared for element "*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']/*[local-name()='VisualElements']/*[local-name()='DefaultTile']" doesn't exist in the package.
```

However, the assets directory does contain the files needed with the naming scheme as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/app-assets:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           3757 Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           4630 Square150x150Logo.scale-125.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           5633 Square150x150Logo.scale-150.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           7504 Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM          15784 Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           7832 Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           9873 Square310x310Logo.scale-125.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM          11802 Square310x310Logo.scale-150.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM          16065 Square310x310Logo.scale-200.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM          35149 Square310x310Logo.scale-400.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1874 Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2284 Square44x44Logo.scale-125.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2867 Square44x44Logo.scale-150.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           3880 Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           7327 Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM            834 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1034 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-20.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1262 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           9912 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1191 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-30.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1321 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-32.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1486 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-36.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           1579 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-40.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2078 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2548 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-60.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2761 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-64.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           3130 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-72.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           3410 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-80.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           4192 Square44x44Logo.targetsize-96.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2415 Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2919 Square71x71Logo.scale-125.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           3689 Square71x71Logo.scale-150.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           4937 Square71x71Logo.scale-200.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           9154 Square71x71Logo.scale-400.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           2119 StoreLogo.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           4004 Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           5036 Wide310x150Logo.scale-125.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           6114 Wide310x150Logo.scale-150.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM           8227 Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png
-a----        8/28/2018  11:21 AM          17693 Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: In your bridged project, do you inlcude the image files in an assets folder? Could you try to provide a simple project sample?

Comment: Yes, the image files are in the assets folder of the unpacked appx. I have put up a simple sample project under [link](https://github.com/davidv1992/testApp), this also includes a release with the unpacked appx folder attached. The README.md contains build instructions that replicate the problem. @BreezeLiu-MSFT

Comment: In your provide sample, I can not find an appx file or an original desktop app to convert. I can not reproduce your issue. If you have a visual studio, you can try to [Package an app by using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net), then compare the Assets files's path with your project to find the problem.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT In the sample, it is an electron app packaged using electron-builder to an appx. Since electron-builder doesnt properly support changing the tile assets, I then unpack the resulting appx to change the assets, and try to repack it. As I understand it, this repacking is effectively the same as creating an appx manually. See the build steps I take in the readme on that repo.

Comment: I can not find testApp-1.0.0.appx in your link sample...

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT That is correct, what I have attached is the unpacked appx after unpacking it and (trying to) change the assets. So the attached zip contains the results of ```makeappx unpack /p testApp-1.0.0.appx /d unpack``` where I have already changed the images in the unpack/assets folder (ie. result after step 5 in the readme). I cannot produce an appx after that final step because makeappx complains on the pack operation (step 6).

Comment: What is your original desktop app type? How could I create a new same app type to test?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT The original app is an electron app. The easiest way to do the packaging into appx from scratch is to follow the build steps in the readme on the repo I linked. To build an entirely new one is simply to clone the electron-quick-start, but I have changed relatively little from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar problems with the adaptive assets. I am using `electron-windows-store` to package my app, but it was also complaining about non-existent files. Turns out there is a `makepri.exe` program that can run before `makeappx.exe` and it prepares the assets for `makeappx.exe`.

I don't know exactly how this works when running the programs manually, but when using `electron-windows-store` setting `makePri: true` in the config allows me to use the adaptive resolution assets. In my case the `makepri.exe` program was downloaded along with the windows SDK, same folder as `makeappx.exe`.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any good documentation on how these programs work outside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

To convert Electron app, you need a step to **Create a Windows executable**. In your sample, it isn’t a real "desktop application": it’s just a bunch of HTML and Javascript files, you need to turn it into a real app then you can convert it using Desktop bridge. You can try to convert your electron app following the blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/03/14/convert-your-electron-app-using-the-desktop-bridge/

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar The blog is from Microsoft blogs and write by Microsoft for helping developers to convert their Electron app using the Desktop Bridge with all details. We will not delete it arbitrarily.